# VBScript 800a005e Error

Tags: vbscript, replace

I'm using old VBScript in my ASP application. Trying to search and replace string using Replace(wholeText, textToSearch, textToReplace) function but i'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a005e'

Invalid use of Null: 'Replace'

/instance/inst_spam_gen_4.asp, line 25
```

And here is my function:

```
Function cleanUpText(txt)

        txt = Replace(txt, "“", """")
        txt = Replace(txt, "”", """")
        txt = Replace(txt, "’", "'")
        txt = Replace(txt, "®", "&reg;")

    cleanUpText = txt
End Function
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not in the function that you are showing, but in the code that is calling the function.

You have gotten a result from the database that contains a `Null` value. You are then calling the function with that value, which causes the error.

If `Null` values is supposed to be valid in the data, you can use the `IsNull()` function to check for those, so that you don't use the value for anything that can't handle them.